# r keep row and column names if value equal X

Tags: r

Following dataset

```
  a b c d e 
X 1 1 1 1 0
Z 1 0 0 1 0
Y 0 0 0 0 0
```

I wan to create to list. One with all the column names whenever at least one value is equal 1 in a column. One list with all the row names (X,Z,Y) whenever at least one row element has the value 1.

I tried:

```
df[Reduce(`|`, as.data.frame(lapply(df)), function(x) x %in% 1),]
```

with no result.

In the end I want

```
x=(a,b,c,d) and z=(X,Z)
```

Comment: your question is quite unclear to me. can you explain `z=(X, Z)`?

Comment: z is the list of row names where at least on row value is >0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
df <- read.table(text = "  a b c d e 
X 1 1 1 1 0
Z 1 0 0 1 0
Y 0 0 0 0 0", header = T)

> df
#   a b c d e
# X 1 1 1 1 0
# Z 1 0 0 1 0
# Y 0 0 0 0 0


names(which(colSums(df == 1) > 0))
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

names(which(rowSums(df == 1) > 0))
# [1] "X" "Z"
```

Comment: was about to post this `colnames(df)[which(apply(df, 2, sum) > 0)]`... :) I like yours better though...

Comment: @Sotos took me a moment to figure out the non-`apply` route :)

Comment: I don't think this method will work correctly if any of the values are negative?

Comment: @Simon - I just tried a couple of examples with a negative and I'm not sure what you're getting at - do you have an example?

Comment: @tospig, Yes. Ironically I love using `rowSums` as they work great also with non-numeric variables.

Comment: @tospig ignore me, I had a momentary lapse of concentration and forgot what the original question asked for for a second

Comment: @Simon :-) it happens

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv")
row.names(df) <- c("X","Y","Z")
```

The df looks like this (I'm using XYZ here whereas in your example you used XZY, but the idea is the same):

```
  a b c d e
X 1 1 1 1 0
Y 1 0 0 1 0
Z 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then to get your rows and columns based on the condition:

```
x = colnames(df)[apply(df, 2, function(value) any(value==1))]
z = row.names(df)[apply(df, 1, function(value) any(value==1))]
```

This will give you:

```
> print(x)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
> print(z)
[1] "X" "Y"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, works like a charm. Is there a way to set the row.names automatically to the first column, since I want to automate it and cant set the row names by hand

Comment: That is going to depend on what format you currently have your rows names stored in. You would have to set it in some way even if you don't type all the rows names by hand. For example, if your row names are in a file, you could read the file into R, then assign `row.names(df) <- the contents of your file`